# How to create Windows 8.1 Boot usb on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, windows

I want to create a bootable USB and there are no ISO's online, so is there any way I can run the mediacreationtool.exr software without Wine ? Because not even Wine is loading that.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create windows bootable flash drive from linux. Just Follow steps given in this link:

http://www.geekthis.net/blog/91/create-bootable-windows-usb-in-linux

Comment: I know that, but there are no Windows 8 ISO's is what I'm saying.

Comment: They can be downloaded from Microsoft, but I think only for Win8, not Win8.1.  And you will need a valid license number.

Comment: This stuff is too old for ubuntu 16.04